# Admob Test Ads showing On Real Device

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I added **AdMob Banner** (with Firebase) to my **Kotlin Android** app. And i publish my app. On Real Device, I see Test Ads.

Comment: Did you change test ad units to associated with your AdMob account ad units? https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, i used my own AdMob account ad units.